# How to start the application under test automatically from SilkTest Workbench?

Tags: java, swing, gui-testing, silktest

I am trying to write a script to test the login function of my application, however, every time I need to manually start the application then the test can go on. I tried adding the application path into the application configuration property of the script file, but got an error of

```
JFrame SetActive method is unsupported
```

Does anyone have idea how to start an application automatically to test?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it is `SetActive` not `setActive` (note the case)?  The first seems wrong [Java naming convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) for a method name.

Comment: Do you have Execute Base State checked for the application configuration for your application?

Comment: >Andrew: Silk Test is using VB.NET as its scripting language.
>Andy: Yes, I did check that option.